# how to add all in all the total in loop?

Tags: c++

It is me again. I want to add the prices in the purchase if I want to buy more items. But I do not know how to do that. For example if, I confirm my purchase and want to buy more items, I want it to add the prices that is confirmed to purchase, and if I finally do not want to buy more items and not to look for more items, that total price would be computed.

```
int main()
    {
        int choice;
        int purchase;
        int quantity;
        double totalChoice1;
        double totalChoice2;
        char view;
        char confirm;
        char buyMore;
        char look;
        double alloy, apex, kraken, aorus;
        double oppo, alpha, rog, huawei;
        double ps4, nintendo, xbox, wii;

        alloy = 69.99;
        apex = 199;
        kraken = 90;
        aorus = 60;

do {
    cout << "What type of items would you like to view?" << endl;
    cout << " [1] Peripherals" << endl;
    cout << " [2] Mobile Phones" << endl;
    cout << " [3] Consoles" << endl;
    cout << " [4] Exit" << endl;
    cout << "Enter your choice: ";
    cin >> choice;


    if (choice == 1) {
        cout << "--------------------" << endl;
        cout << "What peripherals would you like to purchase?" << endl;
        cout << "[1] HyperX Alloy FPS PRO - $69.99" << endl;
        cout << "[2] SteelSeries APEX PRO - $199" << endl;
        cout << "[3] Razer Kraken X - $90" << endl;
        cout << "[4] AORUS K7 - $60" << endl;
        cout << "[5] BACK TO MENU"  << endl;
        cout << "Enter your choice: ";
        cin >> purchase;
        cout << "--------------------" << endl;


        if (purchase == 1) {
            cout << "How many would you like to purchase? ";
            cin >> quantity;
            totalChoice1 = quantity * alloy;

            cout << "The total price for that is " << totalChoice1 << endl;
            cout << "Confirm the Purchase? [Y]/[N]: ";
            cin >> confirm;

            if (confirm == 'Y') {
                totalChoice1; // This is just a trial code.
                cout << "Would you like to buy more items? [Y]/[N]: ";
                cin >> buyMore;
            }
            else if (confirm == 'N') {
                cout << "Do you still want to look for items? [Y]/[N]: ";
                cin >> look;

                if (look == 'N') {
                    break;
                }
            }
            else {
                break;
            }
        }
}
while (purchase == 5 || buyMore == 'Y' || look == 'Y');
cout << "The total price for your items is: " << totalChoice1; // This is also a trial code (totalChoice1)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply missing a variable to keep track of that total. Don't forget to give it an initial value of 0!

There are plenty of minor other issues with your code, so you'll have some more learning ahead. For instance, we find it easier to do bookkeeping in cents, because you can treat them as integers.

Comment: The total that is showing is the last item that I inputted. For example, if I purchase the 1, it is not holding the payment, and if I want to buy more, the last item that I confirmed, is the last total that is showing, it is not adding to the first item.

Comment: @grantfasx: Of course. Each time, you overwrite the past value of `totalChoice1`. That is to say, `totalChoice1` holds the value of the last purchase. You probably want a second variable for all purchases together.

Comment: how can i add the value if i purchase the same item or another item and add them all in all?